# How to perform functional testing of a kafka consumer application?

Tags: scala, testing, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, scalatest

I want to test an application that consumes Kafka messages and writes them to log. Here is approximate representation of it in scala-like pseudo-code:

```
import kafka.consumer.Consumer
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.util.Properties
import java.util.HashMap

object ConsumerApp extends App {
  val topic = new HashMap[String, Integer]()
  topic.put("test", 1)
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName())
  val messageStream = Consumer
    .createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(new Properties()))
    .createMessageStreams(topic)
    .get(topic).get(0)
  for (message <- messageStream) {
    val gotMessage = new String(message.message())
    logger.info(gotMessage)
  }
}
```

The test scenario I have in mind is following:

- Kafka server is started.
- The application is started and connects to the Kafka server, beginning to listen for messages on a specific to topic.
- A message is sent to the topic.
- The application consumes the message and logs it.

Here is the draft of the test in scala-like pseudocode:

```
import uk.org.lidalia.slf4jtest.TestLoggerFactory;
import uk.org.lidalia.slf4jtest.LoggingEvent.info;

abstract class UnitSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with EmbeddedKafka {

}

class ConsumerAppSpec extends UnitSpec {
  "ConsumerApp" should "consume and log messages from Kafka on specific topic" in {
    withRunningKafka {
      val consumer = ConsumerApp
      // interecept logger to be able to test that the kafka message is logged
      val logger = TestLoggerFactory.getTestLogger(consumer.getClass)
      // start the application, but beforehand do something to prevent it infinitely blocking
      ???
      consumer.main(Array())  

      // publish a test message    
      publishStringMessageToKafka("test", "TEST")
      // Confirm that the message has been properly logged
      ???
    }
    EmbeddedKafka.stop()
  }
}
```

My issue is with the are of test code at the first three question marks. If I execute the main() method, it won't terminate, preventing remainder of the test from being performed.

Answer (score 0):

Make it function ...

```
object ConsumerApp extends App {

   def doStuff() {
      val topic = ...
      // more stuff ...
   }

   doStuff()
 }

 class ConsumerAppSpec {
   // ...
   consumer.doStuff()
   // ...
   publishMessage() 
 }
```

**Update**

I guess, I misunderstood the question. Instead of "don't call main", I should have said don't block the thread :)

```
 class ConsumerAppSpec {
   ...
   val futureResult = Future(consumer.doStuff)
   ...
   publishMessage()
 }
```

Comment: How would that help? Wouldn't that just lead to doStuff() blocking the test instead if main()?

Comment: Oh, I guess, I misunderstood what you were asking. See the update :)

Comment: How would you avoid that with kafka consumer though?

Comment: @Worse_Username have you figured this out?